# "Error: unexpected symbol" for a function I'm defining, but I can't identify the source of the error

Tags: r

Apologies in advance for the beginner question but I'm a noob with R for the moment. 
I'm defining a function to run summary statistics on a dataframe, it reads as follows:

```
sumstats = function(y) {
  sumst = sapply(y, function(x) {
    sumstat = c(
      mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      median(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      sd(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      min(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    ) names(sumstat) = c("Mean", "Median", "SD", "Min", "Max") sumstat
  }) aperm(sumst)
}
```

However I keep getting the following error, indicating that something is wrong with the way I want to define the names of my different columns:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"      max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    ) names"
```

Could you tell me what about my syntax is throwing the error?

Thanks

Comment: The line `) names(sumstat) = c("Mean", "Median", "SD", "Min", "Max") sumstat` is missing two line breaks (or semi-colons). The next line is missing one line break. R is telling you where the first line break is missing, i.e., between the `)` and `names(...`.

Comment: I think the most important first step is to break out function x, build it first, fully define the arguments it takes, and then call if from The function y. You must make sure that you pass the appropriate components for x into y or generate them prior to calling it. Also, try to use function names that are descriptive not just x, y l...The issue is grammatical, but separating the two functions will resolve it!

Comment: Thanks so much for the help everyone, that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a new line between the ) for sumstat, and the ) for the names(sumstat), like

```
sumstats = function(y) {
  sumst = sapply(y, function(x) {
    c(
      mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      median(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      sd(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      min(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
    names(sumstat) = c("Mean", "Median", "SD", "Min", "Max")
    sumstat
  })
  aperm(sumst)
}
```

you could also name the items in the vector, and skip the names(sumstat) altogether

```
sumstats = function(y) {
  sapply(y, function(x) {
    sumstat = c(
      Mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      Median = median(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      Min = min(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      Max = max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
  })
  aperm(sumst)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the `names` function on the same row where `c` end. Just alter the formatting of your code.

Note that is is more safe to use `<-` for assigning things to object. `=` is used to pass values to function arguments.

```
sumstats <- function(y) {
  sumst <- sapply(
    y, 
    function(x) {
      sumstat <- c(
        mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
        median(x, na.rm = TRUE),
        sd(x, na.rm = TRUE),
        min(x, na.rm = TRUE),
        max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
      ) 
      names(sumstat) <- c("Mean", "Median", "SD", "Min", "Max") 
      return(sumstat)
    }
  ) 
  aperm(sumst)
}
```